# Matplotlib not showing xlabel in top two subplots when using secondary y axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

This question is very similar to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32215084/matplotlib-not-showing-xlabel-in-top-two-subplots), but the provided answer does not solve my issue as it is not exactly the same. Also the problem has been referred [in this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639383/pandas-plot-hide-x-axis-when-subplots-and-secondary-y), but no answer was provided. I am hoping this example will help someone point me out a workaround.

The problem is when I use a secondary y axis (both with pandas and using twinx), the xlabels and xticklabels disappear on the top subplots.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,4,6],[1,2,6,10],[2,4,12,12],[2,4,12,14],
               [3,8,14,16],[3,8,14,18],[4,10,16,20],[4,10,16,24]], 
              columns =['A','B','C','D'])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)

for xx, ax in zip(['A','B','C'], axes.flatten()):
    meandf = df.groupby(xx).mean()
    df.plot(xx, 'D', ax = ax, legend=False)

    #adding the secondary_y makes x labels and ticklabels disappear on top subplots
    #without secondary_y it will show the labels and ticklabels
    meandf.plot(meandf.index, 'D', secondary_y='D', ax = ax)

    #forcing does not help
    ax.set_xlabel(xx)

# typically it is a matter of using tight_layout, but does not solve
# setting a bigger space between the rows does not solve it either
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: I get a `KeyError` when I run your code

Comment: Not sure about the KeyError, runs fine on my notebook.

Comment: reset your kernel and try again. it doesn't work.

Comment: potentially in some old version you could do `df.plot(x, "y")` which now doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @PaulH, I did that before replying to your comment, not my first rodeo ;)  I am on pandas 0.22.0 though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KeyErrors` aside, sticking with raw matplotlib is probably your best bet:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 2, 4, 6], [1, 2, 6, 10], [2, 4, 12, 12], [2, 4, 12, 14],
     [3, 8, 14, 16], [3, 8, 14, 18], [4, 10 ,16, 20], [4, 10 ,16, 24]], 
    columns =['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)

for xx, ax1 in zip(['A','B','C'], axes.flatten()):
    meandf = df.groupby(xx).mean()

    # explicitly create and save the secondary axis  
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()

    # plot on the main ax
    ax1.plot(xx, 'D', 'ko', data=df)

    # plot on the secondary ax
    ax2.plot('D', 'gs', data=meandf)

    # set the label 
    ax1.set_xlabel(xx)

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. I tried the twinx but I was still plotting the regular axis with Pandas.